# Lucene.NET Structure for a File Path Indexing Solution

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, lucene.net, lucene

I'm trying to make an app, in C# .NET 4.0 and WPF, that indexes:

1. File Names ("taskmgr.exe")
2. File Descriptions ("Windows Task Manager")
3. Absolute Parent Directory ("C:\Windows\System32")

on all the harddrives of a user's computer.

I'm not indexing the contents of the files - just the file names/paths/descriptions. Also note that I'm only indexing practical files of extensions .DOC, .MP3, .EXE, .CS, .CPP. I won't be indexing extension-less files, custom extensions, DLLs, or others of that sort.

I'm completely new to Lucene, and I've read a couple of beginner articles on how to design the document/index structure.

I was thinking that my Lucene document structure could be such that each file is a new document with the three fields listed above as the three key-pair values. Is this recommended? Is going with Lucene the right choice? Would searching for a file name be realtime (the list can, without much lag, dynamically expand and contract with all the possible filenames and paths)?

If any statistics are needed, my harddrive is 450 GB, and I have 681,014 total (all extensions) files and 165,732 folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all the same to Lucene; the question is: what would your users want? If they search for "task", should it match any file which has it in either the name, description or parent directory? If so, then this should probably be all one field.

Will your users want to be more specific (e.g. `filename:task`)? If so, then you will need separate fields.

As an aside: you probably want to use Solr. It's easier to set up, and prevents some common pitfalls.

Comment: Can't have a web app - needs to be a desktop app. As I understand it, this eliminates Solr.

Comment: And could you please elaborate on "if it should match any file which has in it either the name, description or parent directory, it should all be one field?" I have no experience with Lucene, but I thought that if i typed in part of a file description, that Lucene might return the Document object, from which I can access both the file description and the file path. I actually *do* need the file returned if a search matches description, name, or directory. This has to be all one field...?

Comment: You can access Solr from many things, including [C#](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/). Lucene queries are per field, so you can make your searches be `filename:foo description:foo parent:foo` but it might be easier if you just had one field `everything` so your queries are `everything:foo`. You will get back the entire document in either case (provided the fields are stored).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [rather old article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10692/Desktop-Search-Application-Part-1) with dotLucene (now Lucene.net) but very useful for newbies writing Lucene desktop search applications.

Note: Lucene.net 3.0 API has changed significantly, so use this only as a guideline.